# Google Font displays different characters on web and Photoshop

Tags: html, css, fonts, photoshop

I'm using googles "[Windsong](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/WindSong?query=windsong)" font on a website as the logo font. It looks great there:
[image: font on website]

but now I wanted to use the exact same font and put it on a business card and in Affinity (or Photoshop) it looks like this:
[image: font in photoshop]

Which is almost like a different font - I've been trying to wrap my head around whats going on, looking again and again at the website css,

[image: css props of font]

re-downloading the font from google and re-installing it but no different. The css says its cursive, which is not an option in Affinity or even on the google-font site so I'm not sure if that is the issue maybe.

All I found out so far is that it must be the right font as looking at the fonts glyph-chart, it does have these characters, just with some weird dots under or above - but how can I get them to show and what made my website pick these over the 'regular' ones?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the font style is language dependent:

I was finally trying to create custom font styles in Affinity now after I had pretty much tried everything else and here you can see that if the font is set to English, it will have the undesired look it had in Affinity by default:
[image]

Once I changed the langue to something like Turkish I finally got the style that the browser had picked by default, which is the one I wanted:
[image]

Even setting the language specifically to "None" gives the correct character styles:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's the same font but the first letter is capitalized on the first image and the second is lowercase.
The fonts are the same maybe a bit different as of course your browser reads differently the fonts than photoshop which is a graphics tool.

Comment: No the strings are identical both read 
Mara Elena Fotografie 
so in both cases the third word starts with a capital F

Also look at the rest of the Font its like two different versions of the same font 
on the website the letters connect - you see the M flow into the a which connects with the r and so on 
Look at the starting capital E of the second word ... there are quite a few differences and as I said I made very sure the strings are identical

Comment: Check if the creator of the fonts is the same, if its the same the you have the same typo.

Comment: I downloaded the fonts from the same source the source is even linked in my original post. So of course the author is the same

Comment: so the fonts are the same maybe a bit different as of course your browser reads differently the fonts than the photoshop which is a graphics tool.